# Add marker using API on Dronedeploy app marketplace

Tags: dronedeploy

I am exploring the dronedeploy app marketplace and I want to add a location marker using an app.

Is this possible with the current state of the App platform?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you trying to add an annotation to an existing map or draw a marker before a map is created?

Comment: I am looking to add marker after the image is created and capture the latitude and longitude of the marker.